# Can't change character-set-client & character-set-connection from utf8mb4 to utf8 using JDBC for mysql 5.6

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I've this connection string & it was working fine with mysql Connector/J 5.1.40 and mysql 5.5 on windows:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db?noAccessToProcedureBodies=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&characterSetResults=UTF-8&connectionCollation=UTF8_PERSIAN_CI
```

but when I upgraded to mysql 5.6, It seems that JDBC driver automatically changes connection encoding from utf8 to utf8mb4 according to the [mysql change history](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-j/5.1/en/news-5-1-13.html) :

> Connector/J now auto-detects servers configured with character_set_server=utf8mb4 or treats the Java encoding utf-8 passed using characterEncoding=... as utf8mb4 in the SET NAMES= calls it makes when establishing the connection. (Bug #54175)

I don't know why it should treat utf8 as utf8mb4, but I even can't change it manually after connection established:

```
Statement stmt = (Statement) conn.createStatement();
stmt.executeQuery("SET NAMES UTF8 COLLATE UTF8_PERSIAN_CI");
stmt.close();
```

which has no effect on connection state parameters & I've still following situation:

```
character-set-client=utf8mb4
character_set_connection=utf8mb4
character_set_database=utf8
character_set_filesystem=binary
character_set_results=utf8
character_set_server=utf8
character_set_system=utf8
```

This is part of mysql config file:

```
[client]
default-character-set = utf8

[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8

[mysqld]
character-set-server=utf8
collation-server = utf8_persian_ci
```

I really need to change connection encodig to utf8 instead of utf8mb4 because it made some problems in my application.

Any workaround would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this answer will help [somebody](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36155098/4681950)